# Python -> Boost Python + C++ error

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, tensorflow, boost

I am replacing the tensor flow Python code with boost Python C++ code.

The code that runs in Python does not run in Boost Python.

I am creating the mnist example, but the `softmax_cross_entropy` function is strange.

In Python:

```
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=label, logits=logit))
```

In Boost Python:

```
py::object loss_op = py::eval("tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels='label_', logits='logit')", main_namespace);
```

The variables being used, `label_` and `logit`, are of type float32.

```
Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32)
Tensor("add_3:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32)
```

Boost Python shows this error:

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf35-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 1872, in softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2
    precise_logits = _flatten_outer_dims(precise_logits)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf35-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 1628, in _flatten_outer_dims
    output_shape = [product, shape[-1]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is an error of boostpython, it is more like python index issue.
Maybe you should check

```
output_shape = [product, shape[-1]]
```

to see if the -1 should be out side the bracket?